# Can my Windows 8 login password be different from my Microsoft Account password?

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, microsoft-account, lastpass

I am currently logging into Windows 8 with my Microsoft Account. I have recently begun to utilize LastPass and would like to change my Microsoft Account password to a very long and very complex password. Unfortunately, the autologin and copy-paste features offered by LastPass plugins in a web browser are not available on a Windows Login Screen.

As such is there anyway to utilize a Microsoft Account to login to Windows and have the password be different for the computer? Or do I need to setup a local account and just associate it with the Microsoft Account?

Comment: No, if you connect your local user account to a Microsoft Account, you have to use the Microsoft Account to access the account.

Comment: Under the account settings, you can do alternative login methods (PIN, Picture, etc). Though for the actual password, you can only change it there I believe (I.e. change the live password for your ms account).

Comment: @nerdwaller - While you can use the picture password, he would have to store the ( new ) password in order to do that. Picture Password, while secure, has some flaws because of the nature of the beast. You are going from say a 15 character random password to, well lets be honest, hitting semi-obvious places in a picture.  If this is a stationary device, with a single person ( or family )using it, its a great solution.  Furthermore the password can be saved, and one can, automatically log into the account.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm not suggesting it, but I was just giving an alternative way to login to solve the issue.  That said, you're absolutely correct that it's not the greatest solution.

Comment: @nerdwaller - I understood.  My overal response was more to the author then you, but since you raised the point, a directed the clarification about the store password towards you

Comment: @Ramhound - Roger that.  In the future, I'll include the warnings about that kind of stuff.  Good info for those that aren't aware (I probably assume too many people that ask around here do).  Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also set a PIN number to log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use different password with Microsoft Login.
You have to setup a Local Account

alternatively you can use other password prompts like Picture Password or PIN